# Flutter:Instance of 'SharedPreferences'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I was using shared_preferences plugin in my Flutter application, I want to save data when the user selects the city.
But when I try to print it just says;

> Instance of 'SharedPreferences' Unhandled Exception: setState()
> callback argument returned a Future

. (Even if I remove my setState part I get the same error)in my console.

does anyone know the reason??

My text in the in card widget

```
 Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.data.name,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),
```

and when clicked where I saved it

```
   onTap: () {
                            setState(() async {
                              final country =
                                  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                              String name;
                              name=snapshot.data.name;
                              country.setString('name', name);
                              print('here $country');
                          
                            });
                          },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 onTap: () async {
  final country =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
  String name;
  name=snapshot.data.name;
  country.setString('name', name);
  print('here $name);

  });
},
```

Comment: To add some explanation to this answer, the callback of `setState` cannot be async. This is mentioned in the documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: this time it only writes Instance of 'SharedPreferences'

Comment: not getting what you mean? can you explain little bit?

Comment: no, I mean nothing changed when I wrote the solution you said. I still have the same output on my console, it only says Here Instance of 'SharedPreferences' no more

Comment: could you restart the application and re-run app again

Comment: i did but still the same

Comment: You are getting this because you are printing the instance of SharePreference which is country.  Use country.getString('name');

Comment: I don't know how I made such a mistake.:) thank you so much!